# Wordpress database issues - menu not saving correctly, media thumbnails not showing

Tags: menus, database, sql

I am having a problem with Wordpress that I have not ever seen before. I when make changes to any of the menus on my site, they don't save correctly. For instance, I will add a page to the menu, and upon saving, it will be changed to a Custom Link, and it's title will be deleted.

Also, my media items are not saving correctly. In the media library, the thumbnails are not being loaded and the images won't display on the front end.

I have narrowed this down to being a database issue. Going through the process of de-activating plugins and changing themes did not resolve this behavior, but reverting to an older database did. I have already used myPhpAdmin's repair database and optimize database functions, and neither detected any issues. Are there any other known processes to help diagnose database issues?

Please let me know if I can provide any other helpful information.

Comment: Which version of WordPress are you running?

Comment: 4.9.5 (most recent). all of my plugins are up to date as well

Comment: Have you tried creating a new menu or deleting the current menu and re-creating it?